# DAV transport method is being deprecated warning message

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, warnings

I am facing an issue (Warning message) at the completion of uploading the archive to the AppStore.

I have uploaded lots of different versions but this warning I am seeing for the very first time, did anyone having to face this kind of warning message, if yes then please suggest steps to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's what deprecation means. You haven't changed anything, but you probably should.

Comment: That's what my question is.
What changes i need to do in order to resolved this warning.

Comment: I'm seeing this message for the first time too... Did you find any piece of info about that?